# Execute a function

Tags: php, function, pdf

I'm trying execute the function excel() and pdf() with a button, but it isn't working.

I just need list the search, and next I need two buttons, one for generate pdf and another for excel.

```html
<?php 

define('FPDF_FONTPATH', 'font/');
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf=new FPDF('p', 'cm', 'A4');
$pdf->Open();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);


include "conexao.php";
      



$busca = $_POST['palavra'];// palavra que o usuario digitou

$busca_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM carreteiro WHERE nome LIKE '%$busca%' or cidade like '%$busca%' or estado like '%$busca%' or bairro like '%$busca%' or rua like '%$busca%'")or die(mysql_error());//faz a busca com as palavras enviadas


if (empty($busca_query)) { 
    echo "Nenhum registro encontrado.";
}

// quando existir algo em '$busca_query' ele realizará o script abaixo.
while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($busca_query)) {
     
    echo "Nome : $dados[nome]<br />"; 
    echo "Cidade: $dados[cidade] <br />";
    echo "Estado: $dados[estado]<br />";
 echo "Rua: $dados[rua]<br />";
 echo "Bairro: $dados[bairro]<br />";
    echo "<hr>";
 
}



//inicio pdf /////////////////////////////////

function pdf(){
 
$exe = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM carreteiro WHERE nome LIKE '%$busca%' or cidade like '%$busca%' or estado like '%$busca%' or bairro like '%$busca%' or rua like '%$busca%'")or die(mysql_error());


while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($exe))
 {
 $pdf->Cell(3,1,$dados['nome'],1,0,'L');
 $pdf->Cell(4,1,$dados['cidade'],1,0,'L');
 $pdf->Cell(2,1,$dados['estado'],1,0,'L');
 $pdf->Cell(5,1,$dados['rua'],1,0,'L');
 $pdf->Cell(5,1,$dados['bairro'],1,0,'L');
 
 }
 ob_start ();
$pdf->Output();

}


?>

<form action="pdf()"><input type="submit" value="Gerar PDF" /></form>
```

Comment: Would you expand on "isn't working" here - what is the problem you are encountering? Does the PDF generate OK? What happens when you press the button?

Comment: Ah, `<form action="pdf()">` won't work. The `action` attribute is for a PHP script name that will handle the submit operation, something like `generate.php` (which you then need to write). You can also leave it out, and handle the operation in the same file. Either way, you will need `method="post"` in the form tag.

Comment: the pdf generate ok, i need generate from a search, like:

i search for some keyword, and when i found i see a list of thing whit this keyword, i want put this things in pdf and excel with a button

Comment: OK. To start with, remove `action="pdf()"` - it is wrong (I don't understand how the `pdf()` PHP function is called - have you checked that it is really being called?). You also have SQL injection vulnerabilities here, so I would suggest fixing what you have first.

Comment: im trying call the function but this is the problem

Comment: A recent answer I provided on another question might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29989565/how-to-store-form-output-in-a-database-using-php/29991490#29991490

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
<form action="pdf()"><input type="submit" value="Gerar PDF" /></form>
```

to this:

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Gerar PDF" />
</form>
```

In your code, at the appropriate point (I can't quite tell where) you need to add something like the following code. You need to ensure no HTML has been output at this point, since if the PDF is being sent to the browser, you do not want to send a mix of PDF and HTML - it would make no sense.

```
if ($_POST) {
    pdf();
}
```

So, this script acts in two ways:

- When it is visited via `get` it renders the HTML/form
- When it is visited via `post` it creates a PDF

There is probably more work still to do - you probably also need to:

- Output a PDF content type header
- exit so no HTML is rendered

Don't forget to address the security vulnerabilities as well - they must not be ignored.